# Capture text output of error provided in windows popup (via the process error mode)

Tags: c++, windows, dll, error-handling

I'm attempting to use LoadLibrary to load a DLL.  By default, if the library can't be found, it returns code 127 (ERR_MOD_NOT_FOUND), which is fine.  However, if it can be found, and there's some error...say I'm loading libraryA.dll, which needs libraryB.dll to be loaded and it can't find it, it creates a popup box with a helpful error.

This is great, but I'd rather not have the popup box.  In my application, failure to load a library is *possibly* an application failure, but there is still a chance for graceful recovery.  As such, I can't let the application hang while we wait for the user to poke an OKAY button.  However, because it may be a total failure, I would like to be able to capture and store this helpful error message to present to the user at a later time.

I've made it as far as the SetErrorMode function.  Calling

```
SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS);
```

disables the popup, which is great, but I'd still like to be able to somehow fetch the text string describing the error.  As it stands, LoadLibrary still fails with code 127, which is very disingenuous when the error isn't that libraryA.dll could not be found, but that libraryA.dll couldn't load libraryB.dll.

According to the `SetErrorMode -> SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS` [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680621%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The system does not display the critical-error-handler message box. Instead, the system sends the error to the calling process.

so theoretically it should be possible to capture this message, I just don't know how, and the documentation doesn't appear to give any hints.  I've done some google-ing for an answer but either it's not documented anywhere, or I don't know the correct keywords to search for.

So I either

A) Need to figure out how to capture the error silenced by SetErrorMode

B) Come up with some other way to get a useful error message (more useful than "The specified module could not be found") while disabling popups.

I'd appreciate any help you guys could give.  I'm fairly experienced at C++, but my windows-programming-fu is pretty bad.

Thanks!